# .NET - Replace object injected by DI as singleton

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dependencies, singleton, code-injection

My DI service provider has following registrations:

```
services.AddScoped<IProducer, Producer>();
services.AddScoped<IConsumer, Consumer>();
services.AddSingleton<IProduct>(new Product(){Prop1 = "Value 1"});
services.AddSingleton<IFinisherService, FinisherService>();
```

And I use these services somewhere in my app in the following way (I inject, but don't actually use finisherService in the constructor, this is just here for illustrative purposes):

```
Producer(IProduct product, IFinisherService finisherService)
{
var finishedProduct = finisherService.FinishAsync(product);

product.Prop2 = finishedProduct.Prop2;
product.Prop3 = finishedProduct.Prop3;
//...
product.PropN = finishedProduct.PropN;
}
```

```
Consumer(IProduct product)
{
  propN = product.PropN;
}
```

That works fine, but it would be much simpler to do something like this (again, here in constructor just for illustration):

```
Producer(IProduct product, IFinisherService finisherService)
{
  product = finisherService.FinishAsync(product);
}
```

This isn't working because 'finished' `product` is only visible inside `Producer`'s scope. `Product` injected by the DI to the `Consumer` further down the line still has null `Prop2 ... PropN`'s. I'm thinking, I could inject `ServiceProvider` to my `Producer` but I'm not even sure if IOC can be modified after it has been built. Is there a better pattern?

Comment: can you post the implementation of FinishAsync? Are you sure a new product object is not being created internally and returned by the FinishAsync method.

Comment: So the system is only ever concerned with one logical product at a single time for all users for all requests?

Comment: @Durga Prasad Yes, new object is being returned by FinishAsync(). I want to replace one created by DI with this new instance.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad That is correct. The app is actually a desktop client so there is only one user.

Comment: Iff you have one user, and one product, and can only serve one request at a time then you can inject a service that exposes a mutable property and update this property. `interface IProductContext { IProduct Product { get; set; } }`. This all seems a little dubious though since you have `services.AddScoped` registrations

Comment: Can't you modify FinishAsync method to return the same reference that was passed in?

Comment: @Durga Prasad I could, but wouldn’t this just move property assignation chore over there?

Comment: I understand that. My thought process was separation of concerns and putting in single responsibility principle. If FinishAsync purpose was to populate the producer object which is already passed in as a input parameter, I did not see a value addition by returning a new product object instead of populating the existing object. Moreover it solves your problem as well.

Comment: On second thoughts I do not understand how it will be a chore, because the FinishAsync method should already be doing that work because the finishedProduct has all of the properties filled in.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I see. Something like a wrapper class that will hold IProduct property that I can reassign at any time. I like this idea.

Comment: Exactly. I should say that I don't care for the overall design but that is the simplest solution if you stick to it. I would not access the current product via DI, I would create services that had method signatures like `IFinisherService { Task<IProduct> FinishAsync(IProduct product);}` and chain calls together. This makes all of them far more testable and it makes the system easier for humans. In other words, nothing beats the tried and true `param => result` pattern and it is orthogonal to DI.

Comment: From the description is seems that `IProduct` consists of *runtime data*. As described [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/), you should prevent injecting runtime data into your service classes. Instead inject an abstraction (e.g. `IProductRepository`) that allows retrieving the right `IProduct` at runtime.

Comment: @Steven Thank you, yes the Product consist of runtime data. I have got follow up question. The article says: Runtime data should flow through the method calls of already-constructed object graphs.
If my IProduct is registered and injected as a singleton Product it is already constructed so I reckon I’m good?

Comment: But if it is a singleton, how are you going to change its values in a thread-safe manner? Trying to do so will get very complex over time. Instead of injecting products into a constructor, a typical solution that you should research into is (as I already mentioned) the repository pattern. Also double check whether it is actually useful to hide the product behind an `IProduct` abstraction.